# REST API is not responding while more characters given as query parameter

Tags: java, rest

I am working on RESTEasy services to generate API for my application.

I tested with the below code to produce a simple string response,

```
@GET
@Path("/api")
public Response getUsers(@QueryParam("from") String from,) throws ProtocolException,
        MalformedURLException, IOException {        

    return Response.status(200)
            .entity("*************Hi Welcome*********************")
            .build();
}
```

It is working fine with the following url

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/f/api?from=any_string_here
```

But, this response available only while the query parameter value does not exceed 6246 characters.

If the query parameter value more than 6246 chars, there is no response available. Also, the browser network console shows the status code 400.

```
http://localhost:8080/myApp/f/api?from=more_than_6246_chars
```

I read that longer url needs to be send using POST, so I tried also with @POST method too for this, but  browser network console shows the status code 405 and the following appears in eclipse console.

```
Apr 07, 2016 12:52:25 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies processCookieHeader
INFO: Cookies: Invalid cookie. Value not a token or quoted value
Note: further occurrences of Cookie errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
```

Is this longer URL is restricted by browser or RESTEasy application.

What would be the solution for this? Do I need to send more chars to my rest api parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Webservers may reject requests if the URL exceeds a certain size.

Using a POST request alone does not help, you also need to decrease the URL size by putting URL parameters into the POST body.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending the parameters in request headers. I am using Jersey framework and angular JS in the front end. Sometimes I need to send a long JSON string for my application. I am sending it in the request headers and so far, I haven't got any issue like this.

My Rest Service class looks like below :

```
@Path("getStatus/agentName")
public class getStatus(){
    @GET
    public Response getStatus(@HeaderParam("header_name") String header_value){
        String response = "Success" + header_value;
        return Response.ok(response, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
    }
}
```

You can send your parameters in custom headers.

I think this should solve your problem.

Comment: Shreyas Thanks for you reply, Can you pls help on how this api is called in browser as url...

Comment: Your URL should look like considering the example I have given : 

`http://localhost:8080/myapp/f/getStatus/agentName`

Comment: Thats fine Shreyas, what about the agent name, is it possible to have agent name 7000 chars?

Comment: Oh, now I see your misunderstanding. When you send the parameters in the headers, the URL doesn't contains that parameters. When you receive the request and if you are using `@HeaderParam`, your server will try to find the information in the request header and not in the URL. That's where it is different from `@QueryParam` . . you need to set the header and write your information as the value of that header.